# Matlab: Count number of unique strings in the file

Tags: matlab

I need to do the following in Matlab. I have a list of names in tab or comma delimited file. For example,

```
Gregor M. Suka

Mark A. Pizda

Matthew A. Blyad

Mark A. Pizda
```

I would like to load this list into Matlab and count the occurrence of each name in the file, i.e., all but Mark A. Pizda would have 1 occurrence and Mark would have 2.

I usually use howmany.m for this, but when I load the array with textscan function, it gives me cell array which I cannot run through howmany.m count.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe you can use the [Map Containers](http://www.mathworks.cn/cn/help/matlab/map-containers.html). Use the string of name as the key field and it's count as the value field.

Comment: I have a very large dataset, so I am not sure Map Containers is the best way to go. Any other suggestions? This seems to be like a very common task, so there has to be an efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you load the file and get the strings in a cell array:

```
strings = {'Gregor M. Suka', 'Mark A. Pizda', 'Matthew A. Blyad', 'Mark A. Pizda'};
[uniqueStrings, ~, v] = unique(strings(:));
occurrence = accumarray(v,1); %// Or: occurrence = histc(v,unique(v));
```

This gives

```
uniqueStrings = 
    'Gregor M. Suka'
    'Mark A. Pizda'
    'Matthew A. Blyad'

occurrence =
     1
     2
     1
```